# Sending information then getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paysimple

Getting ths error when I'm going to create a payment.. what do you think cause this?? I already checked the view and model..

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Create(FormCollection formCollection)
 { 
   string username = "asa";
   string apiKey = "as";
   string baseUrl = "https://sandbox-api.paysimple.com";
   var settings = new PaySimpleSdk.Models.PaySimpleSettings(apiKey, username, baseUrl);

   var paymentService = new PaymentService(settings);

   var customerPayment = new NewCustomerPayment<CreditCard>
   {
     Customer = new Customer
     {
      FirstName = formCollection["FirstName"],
      LastName = formCollection["LastName"],
      BillingAddress =
        {
             StreetAddress1 = formCollection["StreetAddress1"],
             StreetAddress2 = formCollection["StreetAddress2"],
             City = formCollection["City"],
             StateCode = (StateCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(StateCode), formCollection["StateCode"]),
             Country = (CountryCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(CountryCode), formCollection["Country"]),
             ZipCode = formCollection["ZipCode"]
         }                  
      },
      Account = new CreditCard
      {
       CreditCardNumber = formCollection["CreditCardNumber"],
       ExpirationDate = formCollection["ExpirationDate"],
       Issuer = (Issuer)Enum.Parse(typeof(Issuer), formCollection["Issuer"])
      }, 
      Payment = new Payment
      {
       Amount = int.Parse(formCollection["Amount"]),
       Cvv = formCollection["Ccv"]
       }
      };

     var newCustomerPayment = await paymentService.CreateNewCustomerPaymentAsync(customerPayment);

  return View();
  }
```

My Model from SDK

Customer

```
    [JsonProperty("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("BillingAddress")]
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
```

Address that link in Customer Billing Address

```
    [JsonProperty("StreetAddress1")]
    public string StreetAddress1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("StreetAddress2")]
    public string StreetAddress2 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("City")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("StateCode"), JsonConverter(typeof(TypeEnumConverter<StateCode, BiLookup<StateCode, string>>))]
    public StateCode? StateCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ZipCode")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Country"), JsonConverter(typeof(TypeEnumConverter<CountryCode, BiLookup<CountryCode, string>>))]
    public CountryCode? Country { get; set; }
```

Model of Account Credit Card

```
    [JsonProperty("CreditCardNumber")]
    public string CreditCardNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ExpirationDate")]
    public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Issuer")]
```

Model for payment

```
    [JsonProperty("Amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("CVV")]
    public string Cvv { get; set; }
```

My View

```
 @model WebApplication16.Model.ParentModel

 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Create";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 Create

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ParentModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          </div>
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StateCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StateCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.StateCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.ZipCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.ZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.BillingAddress.ZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreditCard.CreditCardNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreditCard.CreditCardNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreditCard.CreditCardNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreditCard.ExpirationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreditCard.ExpirationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreditCard.ExpirationDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreditCard.Issuer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreditCard.Issuer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreditCard.Issuer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Payment.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Payment.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Payment.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Payment.Cvv, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Payment.Cvv, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Payment.Cvv, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
               </div>
            </div>
             </div>
                 }

              <div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
               </div>
```

Comment: Stop using `FormCollection`! Make your parameter `ParentModel model` and `model` will be correctly bound with the values of your form controls (and you do not have any values for `formCollection["FirstName"]` etc - look at the `name` attributes of the html your generating)